# Missing arguments for method unapply in slick

Tags: scala, slick

I am developing an application using Scala and Slick. I have a table named CarAdvertisement which has a model

```
case class CarAdvertisementModel(id: Int, title: String, fuel: String, price: Int, isNew: Boolean, mileage: Option[Int], firstRegistration : Option[LocalDate])
```

I am trying to declare my schema using slick. My code is as follows

```
  private class CarAdvertisement(tag: Tag) extends Table[CarAdvertisementModel](tag, "CAR_ADVERTISEMENT") {

    def id = column[Int]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)

    def title = column[String]("title")

    def fuel = column[String]("fuel")

    def price = column[Int]("price")

    def isNew = column[Boolean]("isNew")

    def mileage = column[Option[Int]]("mileage")

    def firstRegistration = column[Option[LocalDate]]("firstRegistration")

    def * = (id, title, fuel, price, isNew, mileage,firstRegistration) <> ((CarAdvertisementModel.apply _).tupled, CarAdvertisementModel.unapply)
  }
```

However, the last line

```
CarAdvertisementModel.unapply)
```

gives me an error as

```
Missing arguments for method unapply(CarAdvertisementModel)
```

Can you please let me know as to what I am missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that you don't have also a error like

> could not find implicit value for parameter tt: 
>   slick.ast.TypedType[Option[java.time.LocalDate]]
>   
>  def firstRegistration = columnOption[LocalDate]

If you have one, try adding something like this to your code

```
private class CarAdvertisement(tag: Tag) extends Table[CarAdvertisementModel](tag, "CAR_ADVERTISEMENT") {

  // fast hack to support LocalDate
  implicit val localDateColumnType = MappedColumnType.base[LocalDate, java.sql.Date](java.sql.Date.valueOf, _.toLocalDate)

  // the rest of the code
```

Or you might try to use the latest code of the Slick with merged [PR #1349 Support `java time`](https://github.com/slick/slick/pull/1825). Unfortunately AFAIK there is still no official release with those changes.

Comment: Thanks for the quick update. But I have already tried all these hacks. But somehow did not work for me.

Comment: @ChaitanyaWaikar, then you should provide a real [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) The code I provided in my answer seem to compile, see [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/xMmcBtfASTasfL8PkoAmbQ)